# Permission levels for user exporting list into excelsheet sharepoint 2010

Tags: list, permissions, excel, export

What are the minimum permissions needed for a users to export the list into excel sheets in SharePoint 2010?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to @ToniFrankola https://serverfault.com/questions/73677/disable-export-to-spreadsheet-in-sharepoint-custom-list you need to have permission:

```
[x] Use Client Integration Features
```

In OOTB premission levels this permission is not set only for `Restricted Read` level.

So correct answer to your question is:

Minimum **OOTB permission level** for users to be able to export lists in Excel is `View Only` but minimum **permission** is `Use Client Integration Features`

You can always create your own custom permission level and select only `Use Client Integration Features` permission. (Note that two other permissions are automatically enabled: `Use Remote Interfaces` and `Open`.)

Comment: what about SharePoint 2013, I disable this feature, but users still able to export to Excel. I used script editor web part with css code to disable that ATM. (source : https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8867fadc-c291-408c-8e4e-28faa1fe61f6/hide-open-with-access-and-export-to-excel-buttons)

Answer (score 0):

Try going to Site Permissions --> Permission Levels in the ribbon --> Select the permission level to view its properties and I think your looking for View Items in the List Permissions, not entirely sure but I usually play around with them till I get the desired result.