# Survey security; exported excel file password

Tags: export

It's my first post here. I have a bunch of survey that I made so employees can use them during each call. Some of this surveys have personal details of customers. We have managers who then exports the excel file once a day and uses the data for there reporting.

I want employees to be able to take part in survey but not to be able to export file. And managers to be able to do both. Do you what is the right permission for this? I changed some of the settings of this survey so they can't see other's data but that setting effects managers exported data too. Is there any way I can put password on this exported file so even if employees download it they can view it?

Thanks in advance for your support.

Answer (score 3):

You need to [define a custom permission level](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263239.aspx)  for employees. The easiest way is to copy from one of the default ones.

Once you create your permission level uncheck the following option:

> [] Use Client Integration Features

Create a group that has this permission level, and and your users to this group.

Hope this helped :)

for more information you can visit this link

[export-to-spreadsheet-in-sharepoint](https://serverfault.com/questions/73677/disable-export-to-spreadsheet-in-sharepoint-custom-list)

**Edit**

You might find this [post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/27535/permission-levels-for-user-exporting-list-into-excelsheet-sharepoint-2010) useful as well :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will try it out tomorrow at work. Big thanks :) I will let you know the outcome.

Comment: Tried following your steps Yaron. But as with other things I don't see the option at work for creating new permission. Turns out I don't have the right permissions to do this. Request is sent out to admin but I know it will take them weeks before I get it. (our company have 51 sp sites and one admin!!)

Comment: oh sorry forgot to mention you need administration permissions or atleast have permissions to edit permissions but I thought you already had access to that, but it shouldn't take them time as they can create Permissions on site collection level and can be used in all sites within that site collection however am not sure whats the structure of your portal here :)

Comment: Where I am based SharePoint is very new and we have to fight management to carry on using it. For 700 odd staff there are just two of us and one admin some where in capital. I will give this a go as soon as I get permissions clear.