# SPO Hide navigation lists based on user permissons

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, permissions, navigation, hide-elements

I have a SharePoint Online list contain 2 different permissions for many users.

The permissions are: **Full-Control** and **View only**.

I invited the users to the site, but the problem is the users that have **view only permissions** can see **other lists and site contents** in the **navigation**..that they should not have to access it or see it.

So how can i *hide the site contents and the lists* from the users that got the **view only permissions**?

Thank you!

Comment: are you breaking the permission inheritance at list level??

Comment: I am inviting the users by using "Share" button at the top of the page and giving the user permission from the dropdown. But this invitation is for all the site so how can i invite the user to access only the list ? https://i.imgur.com/30aPbv0.png @Ganesh Sanap

Comment: Are these users going to be added to only one list or multiple lists?

Comment: Only i want them to have access in my site for 1 list which is example"Test List" so they can't see the other lists. @Ganesh Sanap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add users to any particular SharePoint Online list only the you need to break permission inheritance on list and grant then grant the access to user on that particular list.

**Reference**: Search for "Break permission inheritance in SharePoint Online" on below article.

[Customize permissions for a SharePoint list or library](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/customize-permissions-for-a-sharepoint-list-or-library-02d770f3-59eb-4910-a608-5f84cc297782).

Comment: This is what i am looking for, but i got a question since the user can view only i check the ribbon and he can export the list to excel is it possible to disable it for view only users ? https://i.imgur.com/19rTi9g.png Thank you ! @Ganesh Sanap

Comment: Check some helpful information, [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/27535/permission-levels-for-user-exporting-list-into-excelsheet-sharepoint-2010).

Answer (score 1):

Just like Ganesh said, if you need to only share the particular list to the users. Break the permission inheritance for that list and share the list to the users.

And you can get more information about permission levels inheritance here. Check the "Overview and permissions inheritance part"

[Understanding permission levels in SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/understanding-permission-levels?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252funderstanding-permission-levels-87ecbb0e-6550-491a-8826-c075e4859848)